# python. package works in folder A but not in folder B

Tags: python

A noob python question.

I have a package called `TorCtl`, I saved it in `/root/A` and create a file (`useIt.py`) in `/root/A` which uses the package and it works absolutely fine.

now the problem starts when I try to use this package within another project.

I copied `TorCtl` package into `/root/B/C` and created a new file (`useIt2.py`)  (this file is used from another file that is the main for this package.)

when I run main I get import error from TorCtl package. for example:

```
from elixir import *
ImportError: No module named elixir
```

I have no idea why it should work in one folder and not another.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Try removing the package and file completely from the `root\A` and then try again.

Comment: @ρss hmmm \root\A and \root\B have no relation with each other whatsoever. I wonder how that helps, but i'll try it ty.

Comment: @ρss i didn't help mate,

Comment: In which folder is your useIt2.py

Comment: @VincentBeltman well TorCtl is in /root/B/C and so it useIt2.py

Comment: How were you executing useIt.py. And how are you executing useIt2.py

Comment: @VincentBeltman to execute useIt.py is run "python useIt.py" and to excecute useIt2.py I go to top of the project and type scrapy crawl mypackage (the project is a scraper)

Comment: Try  `from B.C.elixer import *`

Comment: @VincentBeltman still no luck mate

Comment: I think it has to do something with scrapy. I don't use scrapy and I can import my libs/packages like you do above.

Comment: @VincentBeltman I have a feeling ur right, just wondering mate, is it possible if I put TorCtl in python library (like globally)